# Why do two similar core, same wire wound inductors have vastly different values?

Tags: inductor, inductance

I wound 2 inductors with similar wire (22 AWG, copper). They have 25 turns each. The cores I bought are similar.

[image: 2 inductors]

One inductor has a value of 1.8 mH and the other one has a value of 3.7 mH:

[image: Values]

What's going on here?

Comment: How "similar" are the cores?

Comment: Not sure about the composition, they should be pretty similar, bought from the same batch of ferrite cores (as you can see). Is it possible both have vastly different composition even though it should be same?

Comment: The datasheet of the core should provide a tolerance value. If there isn't, or if there isn't even a datasheet..There is your answer.

Comment: @S.Goswami Is it possible both have vastly different composition even though it should be same? - If it happens, it must be true! You might hope for better than 2:1 from the same batch - but - some cores are low permeability designed for consistency, and other cores are high permeability, where high means 'as high as possible', and you get what you get as long as it exceeds some threshold. Sounds like you have the second type.

Comment: I count 26 turns

Comment: Yeah but doesn't matter. I have now 18 turns (unwind) and 26 turns and now they are similar value.

Comment: Paint colour seems identical, but current doesn't care. If *they have the same permeability specification* then it is still possible that they measure differently, if one has been previously saturated, while the other has not. To be sure, try de-magnetizing both.

Comment: I hope you don't intend to run any DC bias through those. They're high permeability ferrite cores, they'll saturate right about 1mA. With A_L = 2.7 to 5.5 uH/t^2, and guessing from the wire size these are T50-ish parts (12.5mm OD?), permeability seems to be 10k-21.6k, quite high, but within reason for ferrite.

Comment: Is there any possibility that one of them could be damaged? A hairline crack might account for the difference. Do you have a third core you could wind?

Comment: You could weigh them to verify the quantity of ferrite is the same. Perhaps one has a void.

Comment: Note that the Effective Inductance (AL) of the toroidal core, given in nH/turn^2, has a tolerance of +-25%, as can be seen at https://www.magmattec.com.br/wp-content/uploads /2019/06/FERRITE-139-140-144_00.pdf This variation is probably the cause of the difference in the measured inductance value. Note that L = n^2 x AL, where n = number of turns.